# Firebase Sort the second level child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i sort the second level child in firebase.  I want an alert on a new child is added. I am using java script.
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: to whom you want to alert when a new child is added to your tree

Comment: The added child should be shown on top of my screen .

Comment: Your question is not clear. can you explain bit more like what is 466 and 473 i.e. what id's are those.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried to accomplish your desired result